# image swap click jquery, 3 images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to get the original image and cycle through 2 more images back to it so far I have this, but I dont know how to add an extra image

```
  $('img').on({'click': function() {
    var src = ($(this).attr('src') === '1.png') // current image
        ? '2.png' 
       : '1.png';
   $(this).attr('src', src);

}});
```

Comment: use a counter and loop over it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy solution is to use an array with a counter variable and then loop over it in the click handler like

```js
var images = ['//placehold.it/64/ff0000?text=1.png', '//placehold.it/64/00ff00?text=2.png', '//placehold.it/64/0000ff?text=3.png'],
  counter = 0;
$('img').on({
  'click': function() {
    counter = ++counter >= images.length ? 0 : counter;
    $(this).attr('src', images[counter]);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="//placehold.it/64/ff0000?text=1.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid polluting global namespace I would use a closure as below. Check fiddle - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/jm3nruqg/).

```
$('img').on('click', (function() {
    var arr = [ ... paths to your images];
    return function() {
        var current = arr.indexOf( this.src );
        current--;
        this.src = current > 0 ? arr[ current ] : arr[0];
   }
})() );
```